# JAVA-mergeSort returning array

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I have been having trouble with my mergesort() implementation since im returning an array i get stackoverflow error in mergesotrt(). my merge() works fine this is a small clippet my entire program has an ArraytoString() which work fine and prints to console im adding in alsp im not allowed to change the implementation type like the basic format has to remain 
{37, 27, 43, 3, 9, 81, 10}

```
    public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int start, int mid, int end, int[] temp) {

    int beginHalf1 = start;
    int endHalf1 = mid;
    int beginHalf2 = mid+1;
    int endHalf2 = end;
    //if odd its mid half of
    int index = 0;
    //until arraysect runs out check which is smaller and send to temp
  while (beginHalf1 <= endHalf1 && beginHalf2 <= endHalf2){

    if(arr1[beginHalf1] <= arr1[beginHalf2]){

        temp[index] = arr1[beginHalf1];
        beginHalf1++;
    }else {//>=

        temp[index] = arr1[beginHalf2];
        beginHalf2++;
    }

    index++;
  }//pass leftover items to array
    if(beginHalf1>endHalf1){//right half not done

        while (beginHalf2<=endHalf2){

            temp[index] = arr1[beginHalf2];
            beginHalf2++;
            index++;
        }

    }else if(beginHalf2>endHalf2){ //left half not done

        while (beginHalf1<=endHalf1){

            temp[index] = arr1[beginHalf1];
            beginHalf1++;
            index++;
        }

    }
    return temp;
}


public static int[] mergeSort(int[] arr, int start, int end, int[] temp) {
    //arr unsorted returns sorted copy of that array
    //idk why it doesnt run

    if (start < end) {

        int mid = ((start + end) / 2)-1;//offset for mid for odd size

        mergeSort(arr, start, mid, temp);

        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end, temp);

        merge(temp, start, mid, end, temp);

    }

    return temp;//what do i return 

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {37, 27, 43, 3, 9, 81, 10};//3,9,10,27,39,43

    int length = sortedmerge.length/2-1;//-1 offset for mid


    arrayToString(mergeSort(arr,0,arr.length,new int[arr.length]));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (start < end) {
    int mid = ((start + end) / 2) - 1; //offset for mid for odd size
    mergeSort(arr, start, mid, temp);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end, temp);
    merge(temp, start, mid, end, temp);
}
```

`start` would never be less than `mid` so your first invokation of  `mergeSort(arr, start, mid, temp);` seems to enter the infine loop which causes stackoverflow.